# How to untar multiple files with an extension .tar.gz.aa, .tar.gz.ab..... in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, merge, gzip, tar

How to untar multiple files with an extension .tar.gz.aa, .tar.gz.ab..... until .tar.gz.an each file being around 10 GB in Windows?

I've tried the following commands in my powershell(with admin rights):

```
cat <name>.tar.gz.aa | tar xzvf -

cat : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ cat <name>.tar.gz.aa | tar xzvf –
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Content], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

```
cat *.tar.gz.* | zcat | tar xvf -
zcat : The term 'zcat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ cat *.tar.gz.* | zcat | tar xvf -
+                  ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (zcat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thanks in advance! Would be happy to know of any solutions for linux as well, if anyone else might be facing a same difficulty.

Comment: Questions about command-line archive operations are better suited at SuperUser. SO is [about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) issues, which this question really isn't. The OOM is caused by Powershell's aliasing: `cat` actually means `Get-Content`, it is not the same as *Nix `cat` at all.

Comment: @vonPryz while true, there is going to be some overlap between utility questions and programming questions when it comes to systems languages. That said, this is clearly a misunderstanding of PowerShell syntax and available functions, this is absolutely on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `cat` (an alias for `Get-Content`) to enumerate the contents of a single file and then attempting to pass the parsed file content to `tar`. You were getting the `OutOfMemoryException` due to this. `Get-Content` is not designed to read binary files, it's designed to read ASCII and Unicode text files, and certainly not 10GB of them. Even if you had the available memory I don't know how performantly `Get-Content` would handle single files that large.

Just pass the file path to `tar` like this, adding any additional arguments you need such as controlling output directory, etc.:

```
tar xvzf "$name.tar.gz.aa"
```

You can extract all of the archives with a loop in one go (with some helpful output and result checking). This code is also 100% executable in PowerShell Core and should work on Linux:

```
Push-Location $pathToFolderWithGzips

try {
  ( Get-ChildItem -File *.tar.gz.a[a-n] ).FullName | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Extracting $_"
    tar xzf $_
  
    if( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) {
      Write-Warning "tar returned $LASTEXITCODE"
    }
  }
} finally {
  Pop-Location
}
```

---

Let's break this down:

- `$pathToFolderWithGzips` should be set to the full path to the directory containing your tarballs.
- `Push-Location` works like `cd` but uses the location stack. You can return to previous directories with `Pop-Location`. We change directories to the location we want to extract the files to.

  - Note: PowerShell Core supports the POSIX-like `cd -` and `cd +`
- Wrap the rest in a `try` block so we can go back to the previous folder location after the `try` completes.
- `( Get-ChildItem -File *.tar.gz.a[a-n] ).FullName` enumerates all files in the current directory matching the globbing pattern, but making sure the last letter is one of `a` through `n`. Accessing the `FullName` property gives us only the fully-qualified paths for each file which is all we need to pass down the pipeline.
- `| ForEach-Object { ... }` will pipe all of the filenames from the `FullName` values of the previous expression and iterate over each fully-qualified path.
- `Write-Host` outputs information to the console via the information stream. This text is not programmatically accessible within the current PowerShell session. `Write-Warning` is used further on for a similar effect but is visually distinct.

  - Use `Write-Output` instead if you do want the text to be processed within the same session later on, but usually we want to operate on *objects* over strings if we can.
- `$_` is an alias for `$PSItem`, which is an automatic variable used for pipeline context. Every file path iterated over in the `ForEach-Object` loop will be referenced as `$PSItem`. We pass the archive path to `tar` with this variable.
- `$LASTEXITCODE` is set when the last executable finishes running. This works similarly to how `$?` works in `bash` (though don't confuse this for PowerShell's `$?`). `-ne` is the operator for "not equals"
- `finally` is used after closing the `try` block to `Pop-Location` back to the previous directory. The `finally` block is always executed *regardless of whether the `try` code succeeds or fails.

  - I'm admittedly not good with the `tar` executable so if you know how to control folder output without being in the current directory, you can omit the `Push-Location`,
    `Pop-Location`, `try`, and `finally` bits and just run what is inside the current `try` block, modifying the `tar` command appropriately. You will also need to prefix
    `*.tar.gz.a[a-n]` with `$pathToFolderWithGzips` (e.g. `$pathToFolderWithGzips\*.tar.gz.a[a-n]`) in this case too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and explanation, this code works perfectly for the .tar.gz.aa, but for the subsequent tar files, it shows this error:
```
Extracting [File].tar.gz.ab
tar.exe: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
WARNING: tar returned 1
```

Comment: Does it show a literal `[File]` in the filename of the error or the actual filename? It should be passing the fully qualified path in. I'll take another look in the morning. To be sure, the ones it fails to extract are valid tarballs?

Comment: Thank you, No it shows the actual filename, I have respresented the name as [File] here. Yes the other ones are also valid tar balls just like the first .tar.gz.aa part. It has extracted .tar.gz.aa fully, by the way, so I tried inputting separate file names after .aa in your code, but no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this. I created 5 tarballs `tarball.tar.gz.a[a-e]`, then extracted them using the exact same code in my answer, I'm not getting any unrecognized archive errors. If the archives are valid, perhaps there's something about the archive that Windows' version of `tar` doesn't like? You could always try with another version of it but whatever is going on for you isn't a problem in this code.

Answer (score 0):

These files were created with tar and the GNU split coreutil and are not standalone tar archives.

e.g. on linux this creates `tarball.tar.gz.aa` etc.

```
tar -czf - somedir/ | split --bytes=200MB - tarball.tar.gz.
```

To join these binary files in PowerShell 6 or newer:

```
Get-Content -AsByteStream -ReadCount 10000000 tarball.tar.gz.* | Set-Content -AsByteStream tarball.tar.gz
```

> With large files, adjust ReadCount to copy bytes in differently sized chunks

Then use tar as expected

```
tar -xzf tarball.tar.gz
```